# Can we install SSL on a dedicated unix server ? So that if I open https://<IP address> , it should show secure

Tags: installation, ssl-certificate

It's a CentOS 7 server and I have installed apache webserver and it's running

Answer (score 0):

You can install SSLs from any company (or Certificate Authority - also known as a CA) on your server using these steps.

Steps :-

1. Generate a certificate signing request (CSR).
2. Request the SSL certificate.
3. Install the SSL certificate.

You will need to complete similar to steps for SSL certificates from any company.

Comment: Why the step 1 is required if I am buying the SSL certificate.

Comment: Before you can order an SSL certificate, it is recommended that you generate a CSR from your server or device. When you generate a CSR, most server software asks for the following info: common name, organization name and location etc.
If you aren't sure of the exact company name or location when you generate the CSR, don't worry; we can change and finalize that information during our review process before we issue the certificate.

Once your CSR is created, you'll need to copy and paste it into the online order form when you go to purchase your SSL certificate.